# Cross Mark on the TOP right of the page

Tags: web-app, chrome

I am testing an Application where I see some cross mark on the Header of the form, when I click on the cross mark the form on the page disappear completely(though on refreshing the form is visible again).
Why do we need these cross mark and are they important and necessary(This behaviour is in chrome browser)

[image: Please see the image below]

Comment: Why does it show up again after refreshing? Isn't x-ing out of it saying that you don't want to see that panel anymore?

Comment: Just imagine x-ing out of windows on your computer, but upon restarting, you get all those windows back.

Answer (score 1):

Without context for the application, we can mostly guess as to the why the 'close' button is there. On most desktop  applications/browsers the 'X' is always used as a close button. Be it Windows/OSX/Linux.

Since you're filling a form, I am not sure why it would allow you to close a part of the form, especially since refreshing will just make the item reappear.

Would be please rephrase your question or add more information to make a context?

Comment: its a LMS(Leave Management Application). Actually I was told by the creative people that this is the trend we are following and it does not matters.

Comment: In this case I, I think a typical form would be a more beneficial approach. Smaller fields with required parts for input. This will guide the user to fill in the right details. If the information is required I don't see a reason the the close button is needed in the first place.

Comment: Daniel is right.

Comment: I second what Daniel said and suggest that an accordion-style pattern with collapsible—not removable—areas would make more sense if you *must* have these panels.